# Compile SCSS on Synology

Tags: sass, synology

I've got a DS718+ serving my development environment, PHP/MySQL on the bundled Nginx. Everything seems to work after lots of messing around except I'm used to a SCSS compiler that detects changes and automatically recompiles. I can't seem to find anything on Synology that does this.

I *could* do:

- A Docker. This requires too much work to maintain and overhead to run.
- phpSCSS. I'd have to change my source to serve SCSS and compile on the fly, which breaks my existing dev (and prod) environments.
- Local compilation of SCSS. Then my Synology no longer represents a self-contained development environment.

Does anyone have a working solution or a recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would like a full-version linux platform like debian on synology. So that you can do whatever you want like you do before on your linux boxes.

I recommend you use debian-chroot on synology.

I have compiled a suite of debian-chroot for DSM6.x on almost synology platforms, you can install it on your DS718+ follows https://github.com/OKit-Scripts-Projects/DSM.Customizations/blob/master/App.Debian-Chroot.md

Once you have a debian-8 on your DS718+, you can do anything like before, such as a self-contained development environment.

If there is any problem, feel free to ask me here or open an issue on my github repo.

Comment: That's too much overhead for a simple process. I'm working on a Synology application to do this. It requires much less maintenance than keeping a full `chroot`'d instance (essentially a vhost).

Answer (score -1):

Use Synology Client,and create a local folder naming the folder as it appears on the nas on your pc where you will hold the project files. If you create a two way sync the two folder will mirror each other, and any changes will automatically update.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you understood the question. This isn't about file syncing, it's about how to automatically run a process on the Synology box when a file on a different machine changes.